# MarkLogic Choco

Tags: windows, installation, marklogic, chocolatey

Is there a [chocolaty](https://chocolatey.org/) or similar offcial ML windows installation software package somewhere?
That will be useful for the ML windows enviroment set up automation.

It is possible for follow the [below link](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/create/create-packages) to create the ML chocolaty package. But it will require ML endorsment in order to push the package to make it avaiable to the public.

Comment: I would suggest opening an RFE ticket with MarkLogic Support.  What parts of the installation are causing issues?  You can use the Admin REST commands to do server setup and configuration, which is how I've done Automation in the past.